# No reconoce new Response.Listener en JsonObjectRequest

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio, json, android-volley

Estoy siguiendo este tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBfL5-4Ylgs&list=PLEeNnyP176RemEpW-D-FFnIh3p3bGlFNz&index=5 para poder crear un CRUD y vincular mi BBDD mySQL con una app. No se porque, cuando creo el objeto JsonObjectRequest, en el cuarto parámetro que recibe, que es el Listener y luego también en el ErrorListener, parece como si no me reconociera el **new**, y al probar la app me echa. Adjunto el código de las dos activity que interactuan en este problema que me surge.
La main activity sería esta:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText usuario;
    EditText password;
    Button boton;
    TextView registrate;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        registraId();

            boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    cambio();

                 }
            });

            registrate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    registrar();
                }
            });
        }

    private void registraId (){
        usuario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Usuario);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Contraseña);
        boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        registrate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.registrate);
    }


    public void cambio (){
        Intent cambiar = new Intent(this, Inicio.class);
        cambiar.putExtra("id_usuario", usuario.getText().toString().trim() );
        startActivity(cambiar);
    }
    public void registrar (){
        Intent registrar = new Intent(this, Registro.class);
        startActivity(registrar);
    }
}
```

Y la otra activity es esta

```
package com.example.calculadora;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Inicio extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText informacion;
    String id;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras!=null){
            id=extras.getString("id_usuario");
        }

        informacion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.info);
        datos();


        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    }

    private void datos () {
        String URL = "http://10.241.42.231/xrv/mostrar.php?id=" + id;
        JsonObjectRequest datosJson = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                URL,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        String nombre, email, contrasena;
                        try {
                            nombre = response.getString("nombre");
                            email = response.getString("email");
                            contrasena = response.getString("contrasena");

                            informacion.setText(nombre + " " + email + " " + contrasena);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }
        );
        requestQueue.add(datosJson);
    }
    }
```

Es en esta segunda, en el método datos donde surge el problema que comento.

Adjunto una imagen también para que se pueda ver lo que comento[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tanto el new Response.Listener(), como el new Response.ErrorListener() da la sensación de que no los está reconociendo. Todo lo demás funciona bien, es cuando llamo a este método en el onCreate cuando me expulsa de la app.

El php de la base de datos funciona bien porque con postman he podido comprobar que funciona, y tengo una ventana de registro donde en la propia app introduzco los datos y se agregan a la BBDD, el problema lo tengo cuando intento mostrar los datos.

Muchas gracias!!

**¡¡Edición!!**

Edito el mensaje para poder introducir el mensaje que me aparece en el logcat de error, que como me comenta Cedano, no lo entiendo jejeje

Cuando digo que me echa, me refiero a que cuando pulso el botón me cierra la app y me devuelve a la pantalla principal del emulador.
Mil gracias!

> 2024-01-31 00:24:04.338  9970-9970  AndroidRuntime
> com.example.calculadora              E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.calculadora, PID: 9970
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.calculadora/com.example.calculadora.Inicio}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt
> to invoke virtual method 'com.android.volley.Request
> com.android.volley.RequestQueue.add(com.android.volley.Request)' on a
> null object
> reference
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
> method
> 'com.android.volley.Request
> com.android.volley.RequestQueue.add(com.android.volley.Request)' on a
> null object
> reference
> at com.example.calculadora.Inicio.datos(Inicio.java:71)
> at com.example.calculadora.Inicio.onCreate(Inicio.java:36)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
> at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué significa que *te echa*? En vez de capturas de pantalla, revisa el Logcat de Android Studio y si no entiendes el mensaje de error, cópialo y pégalo en la pregunta.

Comment: El mensaje de error te está diciendo claramente que `datosJson` es nulo. Puede que la petición a esa `URL` no te esté devolviendo un objeto JSON válido. Para verificar eso, puedes imprimir el valor de `URL` y probarlo directamente en tu navegador. Copia la respuesta y valídala en un validador en línea, por ejemplo [este](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com).

Comment: Los métodos que mencionas que no los reconoce, imagino que lo dices porque están en gris, deberías probar a mantener el ratón encima de las cosas y leer las explicaciones que te da el IDE. Si no lo reconociese el código no compilaría, están en gris porque crear clases internas anónimas es totalmente innecesario y lo recomendado es utilizar una lambda, si te fijas cuando pasas el ratón por encima de ese código gris el propio IDE te dará la opción de convertirlo a lambda con un click. Es más legible y mucho más corto de escribir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se describe aquí:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
> method 'com.android.volley.Request
> com.android.volley.RequestQueue.add(com.android.volley.Request)' on a
> null object

Que indica que el error se produce en este punto, al tratar de llamar el método `.add()` pero `requestQueue` tiene valor null, ya que no se ha inicializado:

```
requestQueue.add(datosJson);
```

La solución es inicializar `RequestQueue` y posteriormente llamar el método `datos()`, esto dentro de tu método `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio);

        ...
        ...
        ...
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        datos();


    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Por el momento eso ha resuelto el problema de que me eche de la app, ahora tengo que ver cómo soluciono la respuesta del método. Probé como puso Benito a hacerlo con lambda y no cambio nada, y respecto a la URL como dijo Cedano, en postman me sigue dando el dato de la consulta que hago por PHP.

Comment: Con esta respuesta se soluciona el problema planteado en la pregunta. Ahora debes revisar la respuesta que obtienes al realizar la petición,especificamente revisar que obtiene la variable response del método onResponse(), te sugiero agregar esto en otra pregunta.

Comment: Solucionado!!! Muchisimas gracias, si si, tenías razón, luego solo fue que tenía la URL con la ip del wifi y me habían puesto la conexión con el cable, en cuanto cambié el orden del método y puse bien la URL ya ha ido todo bien! Mil gracias!!!